# KLEE convert non-symbolic variable to symbolic

Tags: variables, symbolic-math, klee

How can I convert a non-symbolic variable (i.e the variable is not declared symbolic in the input program) to symbolic in KLEE

Answer (score 1):

You either need to explicitly call `klee_make_symbolic()` in the input program, or you can hack KLEE itself so that it considers a variable as a symbolic one. There's no straight/easy way to convert a non-symbolic variable to a symbolic one without some hacking.